# How much space does a field take in Elasticsearch index?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Is there an API or some other way to find out how much disk space a field is taking in an Elasticsearch index?  We'd like to pare down on some fields but without knowing how much space a field takes, it's shooting in the dark.

We use Elasticsearch, but I'm also OK with looking at a single Lucene index (=ES shard) for this information.

Comment: Are your fields analyzed or not? If yes, what kind of analyzers do you have for those fields (standard, etc)?

Comment: Two great articles to read in order to better understand the storage requirements of your ES documents: [The true story behind Elasticsearch storage requirements](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-storage-the-true-story) and [part 2](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-storage-the-true-story-2.0)

Comment: @Val Thanks.  Yes, analyzed - we use an ngram analyzer with size 1-5.  The article compares total index size, whereas I'd like to know which fields are hogging the index.

Comment: You could first have a look at your fielddata and see how much fielddata space your fields are using `curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/fielddata?v'` It's not the whole story but that's a good start

Comment: @Val true, but a lot of fields are not being used for aggregations, etc.  So no fielddata for them.  Is there another way?